# Activereports PageReport creation by using custom data

Tags: c#, activereports

I wanna create a page report based on my custom class and my PageReport contains a table inside.

Say for example I have a Customer data class as follow

```
Class CustomerData 
{
  string name;
  string id;
  string address;
}
```

and I create a `List<CustomerData>` CustomerList which contains all my customer data. I want to assign this data as the datasource for my Pagereport. I know In SectionReport we can do like this. But how to assign my list of information to PageReport. Could anybody help me

Ultimately I am expecting a output like something below

```
----------------------------------------------
|Name       |      ID        |     Address    |
----------------------------------------------
|Name1      |      ID1       |     Address1   |
----------------------------------------------
|Name2      |      ID2       |     Address2   |
----------------------------------------------
|Name3      |      ID3       |     Address3   |
----------------------------------------------
```

### update

ComponentIdInfo is one of the field

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe provide a working example of the [SectionReport version](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: my requirement is simple create a page report from a list of data. Please check the question. I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do, something like this:

```
        this._rptPath = new FileInfo(@"..\..\PageReport1.rdlx");
        this._definition = new PageReport(this._rptPath);
        this._definition.ConfigurationProvider = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Configuration.DefaultConfigurationProvider();

        this._runtime = new PageDocument(this._definition);
        this._runtime.LocateDataSource += this.runtime_LocateDataSource;
        this.YourViewer.ReportViewer.LoadDocument(this._runtime);
```

And on your `runtime_LocateDataSource` event, Add the following code:

```
private void runtime_LocateDataSource(object sender, LocateDataSourceEventArgs args)
    {
        object data = null;
        string dataSetName = args.DataSetName;
        string dataSourceName = args.DataSourceName;

        if (StringsAreEqual("DataSource1", dataSourceName))
        {
            if (StringsAreEqual("DataSet1", dataSetName))
            {
                data = CustomerListDataTable;
            }
        }

        args.Data = data;
    }

    private static bool StringsAreEqual(string str1, string str2)
    {
        return string.Compare(str1, str2, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0;
    }
```

Please note that you have to create a `DataSource` named `DataSource1` and `DataSet` named `DataSet1` in your page report. And match the column names of `DataSet1` to `Customer's` class `public properties`.

To get to the `Add DataSource` , right click on just outside of your `page report` (gray area) and select `property` and look for `DataSource` in the `property` window.

**How to Add DataSource/DataSet**

- In the Report Explorer, right-click the Data Sources node and select the Add Data Source option.
- In the Report Data Source Dialog that appears, select the General page and in the Name field, enter a name like DataSource1.
- Right click data source node and select the Add Data Set option.
- In the DataSet Dialog that appears, select the General page and enter the name of the dataset as DataSet1. This name appears as a child node to the data source icon in the Report Explorer.
- Go to the fields tab and enter your DataSet's fields (columns) there

*Please note that if you cannot find `Report Explorer`, go to `Visual Studios` `View` menu and go to `Other Windows`.*

Comment: I can set the Dataset through table properties. How to set the datasource?

Comment: @ ANewGuyInTown, Thanks I found it from the view menu. Now my runtime_LocateDataSource doesn't get invoked. Why is that? (When it will get invoked)

Comment: Did you try giving the full path of your report? `new FileInfo(@"FullPath/YourReportName.rdlx");`

Comment: Can you post how did you `enter` your `fields` for DataSet? (a screenshot)

Comment: Please check the update. "Specified method is not supported" that is the error message now

Comment: I hope it couldn't load the dataset. Can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: Can you see the "Green +" on the top right, Add name,id,address in the "Fields".  First, with "red cross" sign , delete "ComponentIdInfo" and then start adding these fields with "Name:" and "Value:" being "same". (e.g. Name: Address and Value: Address)

Comment: I did so. but not working at all. You can create a small sample and try. you will get the error like                                                                                      An unexpected error occured. Additional information: 'No data has been set. Please specify either a DataSet has single table, DataTable or a DataView to use'
   at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.PageDocument.#0Kf(Boolean forceDataRefresh, Boolean forceParameterDataRefresh)
   at

Comment: Okay try converting to your `list` to `datatable` and set `data=datatable` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Hope you can edit the answer or else I will update my sourcecode. Thanks :-)

Comment: Downvote, because this doesn't really answer the OP's question - how do you invoke PageDocument.LocateDataSource without such a viewer?  For instance, if you're generating a PDF of a PageDocument, you're not going to be using a Viewer of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to implement can be achieved using Object DataProvider in a RDL/Page report. Please check this [link](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/Bind%20Page%20Reports%20to%20a%20Data%20Source.html) for details and a code sample. Please pay attention to Object Provider topic under the "Unbound Data Source" section.